How to create proxies for Davinci Resolve Dolby Vision Video?
I'm working with 8K Canon RAW footage and need to perform color grading for a Dolby Vision project in DaVinci Resolve. Given the massive file sizes and high-resolution, my system struggles with smooth playback and editing. I understand that creating proxies can help, but I'm unsure of the best approach to generate and use these proxies effectively within DaVinci Resolve while ensuring the final output meets Dolby Vision standards.
These are my current settings

This is after color grade

This is after Export

